# Play Framework MVC mailer

Tags: java, playframework-1.x, mailer, playframework

I have a application that sends an email through Play MVC mailer plugin, while register and Forgot password. I need to know how to send bulk email using the same plugin. That is I need to send email to all user when the new user is registered.

Here the Code I am using to send an email:

```
 setSubject("Confirm Registration");
 addRecipient(ua.username);
 setFrom("support@xxxx.com");
 send(ua, user);
```

Here I need to know how to add multiple Recipient and send an email?

Comment: I don't get it... What's the question?

Comment: how to add all user mail id in addRecipient?

Comment: @MadTech Could you please provide a link to that plugin? I cannot find it anywhere. Or do you perhaps mean the [`play.mvc.Mailer`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/emails#mvc) class that's built into Play 1?

Comment: Link for Mailer [http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.0.2.1/emails]  and [http://www.docjar.com/html/api/play/mvc/Mailer.java.html]

Comment: You set Playframework-2.0 tag and yet you link to Play 1.0 documentation. Which one are you using?

Comment: Sorry for that.. I am using play 1.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy. You can just call `addRecipient` multiple times to add more recipients. Or you can pass multiple recipients to it, like this:

```
addRecipient("alice@example.com", "bob@example.com", "charlie@example.com");
```

Or you can pass an array to `addRecipient`:

```
String[] rcpts = new String[] {"alice@example.com", "bob@example.com"};
addRecipient(rcpts);
```

Or you can take a `List`, make an array from it, and then pass it:

```
List<String> rcptsList = new ArrayList<String>();
rcptsList.add("alice@example.com");
rcptsList.add("bob@example.com");
addRecipient(rcptsList.toArray(new String[rcptsList.size()]));
```